# log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mkfntmap)

Tags: minionpro

I have a problem with MiKteX2.9 recently re-installed and MinionPro.
Doing pdflatex on the MWE below, I get

```
    pdflatex.exe (file MinionPro-Regular-tlf-sc-t1): Font MinionPro-
Regular-tlf-sc-t1 at 545 not found
```

But the font MinionPro-Regular-tlf-sc-t1.tfm exists in the tfm/adobe/MinionPro directory of MiKTeX2.9. Additionnally other fonts of MinionPro are found (even the correct size is not found and an alternative is used).
The title of the question comes from trying to do the following commandline in admin mode:

```
 initexmf --admin --mkmaps
```

I get the following message in the cmd box:
    log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mkfntmap).
    log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
Now, of course I checked that the system was up to date in both admin and user modes. So I uninstalled the log4cxx package and reinstalled it. Ran fndb but still get the error in both the MWE and initexmf --admin.
BTW initexmf --mkmaps works (or at least doesn't complain).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section title}
  \subsection{Some subsection title}
  Some text
  \textsl{Slanted text}
0123456789\figureversion{lf}123456789
    \scshape{Small Capitals}
\figureversion{lf,tab}

0123456789\figureversion{lf}123456789
\textsc{Hello} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you recently install MinionPro?

Comment: The error message means that the map-files are not correct (tfm are not relevant here). If only one minion pro font  fails it could mean that the map-file is faulty. The logger error sounds like a bug but as I don't have a multiuser system I can't test.

Comment: @bernard, yes as I completely re-installed MiKTeX2.9, I had to reinstall the MinionPro files. I used the other installations of MinionPro that I have on other systems. In this way, I know that I have all the files. All this reinstall business is due to the fact that a perfectly working MiKTex2.9 installation on windows7 got bugged when I updated it recently (last week) after waiting a full 1.5 month since beginning of October so as to be sure that all the bugs from recent updates were cleared away. I have 2 other systems that work correctly (one on Win8 x64, another on Win7).

Comment: @Ulrike which map files would that be? I have same for all my 3 computers. 1 is in fonts/map/divps/adobe/MinionPro.map. And in any case, a map file should be updated with updmap, right? My updmap says: map MinionPro.map only.

Comment: BTW, on my perfectly working MiKTeX2.9 in the office, the command initexmf --admin --mkmaps also gives the log4cxx error. Why should that be?

Comment: I don't have minion pro, so I can't check if it looks for the correct font. Regarding the log4cxx error, I suggest that you make a bug report on the miktex bug tracker.

Comment: @Ulrike I don't have the autorization to create a bug report on: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/? How can I do that? Sorry, found how!

Comment: No I can't. MinionPro is a rather complicated package with variants and without exact information which files you exactly did install it is difficult to debug (and with the information it is still time consuming).